# How to call each 4 values out of 40 values in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a column matrix with 40 values. Say,

```
1
4
5
2
4
1
9
.
.
.
2
```

How can I call every four values and average them until it reaches 40th? I managed to do in the following way but is there a better way? Beste!

```
i = 1, 4
avg1 = avg + avg(i)

i = 5,8 
avg2 = avg + avg(i)

i = 9,12 
avg3 = avg + avg(i)
```

.......

```
i = 37,40 
avg10 = avg + avg(i)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. i = 1, 4 on it's own isn't even a valid statement. What values are going into your average, and what array is 'avg'?

Comment: 1. Ok I made it short like that instead of putting do-enddo.

Comment: 2.'avg' is the average value of consecutive four numbers. avg1 = first four values, avg2 second four values and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a couple of iterations to get the syntax right, but how about this?

```
integer, parameter, dimension(*) :: a = [ 1, 4, 5, ..., 2 ]
integer                          :: i
real, dimension(10)              :: avg

avg = [ (sum(a(i * 4 + 1 : (i + 1) * 4)) / 4., i = 0, 9) ]
print *, avg
end
```

Comment: Showing my antiquity: ... That's Fortran?  Wow!  It has morphed since Fortran-77 (let alone Fortran IV or Fortran 66)!

Comment: @ Jonathan: Nice, isn't it? That's what thirty+ years and four standard revisions can do to a language. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
program testing

   implicit none

   integer, dimension(40) :: array
   real, dimension(10)    :: averages
   integer                :: i, j, k, aux

   array(:)    = (/(i, i=1,40)/)  ! just values 1 to 40
   averages(:) = 0.0

   k = 1  ! to keep track of where to store the next average

   do i=1,40,4 ! iterate over the entire array in steps of 4
      aux = 0  ! just a little helper variable, not really required, but neater I think

      do j=i,i+3 ! iterating over 4 consecutive values
         aux = aux + array(j)
      end do

      averages(k) = aux / 4.0
      k = k + 1
   end do

   print *, averages

end program testing
```

This is the output:

```
2.500000       6.500000       10.50000       14.50000       18.50000    
22.50000       26.50000       30.50000       34.50000       38.50000
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you canavian but I think I failed to explain my problem. :(

Comment: @SM: I think canavanin's answer is correct as well (just longer than mine). I haven't looked at the code in depth, but the final result is correct; he just used a different input array.

Comment: @eriktous Your method and mine yield the same result, both seem to be correct, yours is far more elegant though. But PLEASE don't 'he' me, not all people on SO are male.

Comment: I apologise. I did my best to type your user name correctly, and then I go and make such an ignorant mistake.

Comment: I do not know what am I missing here. But I do not see how two of the programs are yielding the same results. The first four average is 1, 4, 5 and 2 is not 2.5. I think cana used 1-40 as input while erik used the input I gave. Thanks for correcting me otherwise.

Comment: @SM You are right, the results differ as the input arrays differed, but if I plug (1..40) into eriktous' method it yields the same average values as mine. I simply picked (1..40) in my program as your example did not include a full 40 items array.